# success toastr not visible until dismissing (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, toastr, angular-toastr

I'm trying to create a toastr success banner for my web page. The page has data in an ng-grid, with a button component that creates a modal for editing the grid values. After saving the data, a banner should pop up saying the edits were made successfully. I made a custom toast component based on this example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-toastr-custom) but it doesn't appear. I can click on where the toast is supposed to be but it doesn't become visible until it's being dismissed, at which point the dismiss animation happens. Does anyone have any experience with this error? I couldn't find anything online (if this helps, I'm using Angular 8 and Angular powered Bootstrap)

I've tried using toastr as shown in the angular powered bootstrap documentation, but the only thing that makes anything appear at all is this custom toast I found online

(due to the size of the project I wouldn't be able to post all the code - the toastr code is the same as in the link with this one exception:)

```js
toastrSuccess()
  {
    this.toastRef = this.toastr.success("Edit has been saved successfully",null,
    {
      tapToDismiss: true,
      toastClass: "toast border-green",
      closeButton: true,
      timeOut: 3000
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please post some code